# Windows server 2012, cname record returns http error 404, Is my iis blocking cname records?

Tags: iis, dns, windows-server-2012-r2, cname

I'm testing a cname record to a domain on my windows server 2012 r2 for future purposes.
I have this website => http://hiligolan.co.il/ which is already running.
This is the binding setup
[image: iis site binding]

Now I'm trying to set a different domain to the one I mentioned above using a cname record
[image]

When I'm surfing to http://rideme.co.il/ it returns http not found (as you can see)
Checking the ping shows no problem
[image]

So I assume that maybe the problem is at the server,
Could it be that something in the iis configuration blocking it?

note: I'm not looking for 301/2 redirect, what am I looking for is that anyone who will surf http://rideme.co.il/ will actually see http://hiligolan.co.il/ website but under rideme.co.il domain.
note 2: I'm not looking to add every other domain on my iis host binding (assuming I have thousands domain), I just want it to be "open" to all, allow every domain referring cname to => http://hiligolan.co.il/ to display it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicit ask IIS to only forward HTTP requests whose `Host` header contain `hiligolan.co.il` with that site binding.

Therefore, any request with `Host` header of `rideme.co.il` is not forwarded and 404 makes perfect sense.

The fix is also easy, to add a second site binding for the new domain.

#### Reference

https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Works like a charm now, Thank you vary much